# SQL Server: how to change the default value of the ONLINE property for an index?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I need to change the default value for the `ONLINE` option of almost all of the indexes to `ON` so that rebuilding an indexes with this script:

```
ALTER INDEX [Index1]|ALL ON [Table1] REBUILD;
```

will do the same as:

```
ALTER INDEX [Index1]|ALL ON [Table1] REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON);
```

I have to do it without recreating the indexes.

However, it is strange that creating an index with this script:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index1] ON [Table1]
(
  [Column1] ASC
) 
WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

results in an index with the `ONLINE` option set on `OFF` :-??

---

**The fix:**

Figured out that this cannot be done. The `ONLINE` option is not saved anywhere, it affects only the current statement that creates or rebuilds the index, even though some of the options are saved in `sys.indexes` table.
Not specifying `ONLINE` option runs the script with the default value `OFF`.
The fix is to update all rebuild index scripts with explicitly `ONLINE` option on `ON` and to make sure it will run on a SQL Server version that supports this (Enterprise and Developer editions) and that will rebuild online only allowed indexes.
The indexes that cannot be rebuild online are:

- Disabled clustered index
- Disabled indexed view
- Image, ntext, text, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), XML index
- Columnstore index
- Index on a local temp table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to change the default value for the ONLINE property.

`ONLINE` like `SORT_IN_TEMPDB` is not an index property, it's just an option of `CREATE`/`ALTER INDEX` statement.

So this option affects only the current statement and is not saved in metadata for an index.

Comment: Seems that those options:
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS and  FILLFACTOR are persisted. I can see that when generating a CREATE INDEX script from the created index.

Comment: >>>Seems that those options: ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS and FILLFACTOR are persisted.<<< that is correct. but it's different for other 2 options I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Sure, but being an option and not a property doesn't mean it is not persisted. So some options are persisted in the 'sys.indexes' table, some are not. 
Thank you, @sepupic!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
USE [DATABASE_NAME];
GO
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print 'rebuilding indexes in table: ?'", @command2="ALTER INDEX ALL ON ?
REBUILD WITH (ONLINE=ON)";
GO
```

- Note: The above script assumes that your current edition of SQL
  Server supports online index rebuild. In a different case you can
  modify the script to perform the index rebuild offline.

Comment: The statement 
'ALTER INDEX ALL ON TAble1 REBUILD WITH (ONLINE=ON)'
rebuilds the index with the explicit option, I want to avoid that.